# How do I create a .env file for a project to hide API key

Tags: javascript, reactjs, macos, terminal

Trying to create a .env file to hide an API key in my React project. Using the terminal in the root of my project I tried touch .env - no response, then I tried mv .env and now I'm getting:

usage: mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source target
       mv [-f | -i | -n] [-v] source ... directory

Comment: So `touch` doesn't give any feedback if it succeeds, it just silently creates the file. If you type `ls -la` you'll see it there. Secondly the move command, `mv`, requires you to specify WHERE to move it to -> `mv what_to_move where_to_move_it`, e.g. `mv .env ~/Project/MyProject`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Maybe it already created, but hidden in you directory. Try to see it using

```
ls -a
```

Comment: Hm, it seems like it's hidden.Do you know how would I be able to access it and put data on the file if I cant see it?

Comment: using `nano .env` will open the IDE in the terminal so you can type your code directly from the terminal. I think your main IDE will can see the .env file also. Just open your IDE and open it directly from IDE.